# avoiding unwanted page break in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

While printing resultset using jasper api, I am facing one problem.

**Description :**

**Report format :**

```
GroupA(GroupHeader)

SubGroupName(SubGroup Header)

....Data(Detail Section).....
```

**Condition :**

If my subgroup header or GroupHeader appears to be at the bottom of the page i want to insert a page break,so that both header sections as well as data appears on the next page.

Example :

**Actual Output :**

```
GroupA(GroupHeader)

SubGroupName(SubGroup Header)

<unwanted Pagebreak>
....Data(Detail Section).....
```

**Expected Output :**

I want to avoid unwanted Pagebreak.so that my output will look like ,

```
GroupA(GroupHeader)

SubGroupName(SubGroup Header)

....Data(Detail Section).....
```

My JRXML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Account Sub Sub Group Report" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Empty">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="P_Company" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="P_UserName" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="P_Criteria" class="java.lang.Object" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["' '"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="P_Criteria_Code" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["' '"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="P_Criteria_Name" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["' '"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="P_Criteria_Suid" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[-1]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="P_Criteria_String" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="P_ReportName" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Ankitha\\DIS\\ws\\dis-services\\src\\main\\resources\\report\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![----Query String----]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ACGR_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ACSG_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ACSG_NATURE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ACTP_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ASSG_CODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ASSG_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ASSG_ISLIMITAPPLICABLE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ASSG_LIMITFROM" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ASSG_LIMITTO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ASSG_ISBUDGETAPPLICABLE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ASSG_BUDGETAMOUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ASSG_SEQUENCE" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="ReportTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.reporttitle}]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="AccountGroupName">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACGR_NAME}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="17">
                <line>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="1" printWhenGroupChanges="AccountGroupName"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.01"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="1" width="802" height="16" forecolor="#8E6531"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="11" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.accountGroupName}+" "+$F{ACGR_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="AccountSubGroupName">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACSG_NAME}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="15">
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="15" forecolor="#404D71"/>
                    <box leftPadding="20"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.accountSubGroupName}+" "+$F{ACSG_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="51" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="1" y="0" width="801" height="51"/>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_Criteria_String">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_Criteria_String}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_Criteria_Code">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_Criteria_Code}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_UserName">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_UserName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_Company">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_Company}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_ReportName">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{ReportTitle}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_Criteria">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_Criteria}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_Criteria_Suid">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_Criteria_Suid}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_Criteria_Name">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_Criteria_Name}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "Header.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="33">
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="33"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.01" lineColor="#333333"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.01" lineColor="#333333"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.01" lineColor="#333333"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.01" lineColor="#333333"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.01" lineColor="#333333"/>
                </box>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="214" height="33" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="214" y="0" width="79" height="33" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.code}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="293" y="0" width="59" height="33" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.accounttype}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="652" y="0" width="67" height="33" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box rightPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.budget}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="480" y="17" width="62" height="16" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box rightPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.inhouselimitto}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="352" y="17" width="65" height="16" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.applicable}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="542" y="17" width="47" height="16" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.sequence}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="589" y="17" width="63" height="16" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.applicable}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="719" y="17" width="83" height="16" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.nature}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="417" y="17" width="63" height="16" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box rightPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.inhouselimitfrom}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="352" y="0" width="65" height="17" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.limit}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="417" y="0" width="125" height="17" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box rightPadding="0"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.inhouselimit}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="542" y="0" width="47" height="17" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.reporting}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="589" y="0" width="63" height="17" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.budgetappl}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="719" y="0" width="83" height="17" backcolor="#CCE6F5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.report.assg.account}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="19">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="1" y="0" width="800" height="18" backcolor="#F2F2F2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_COUNT}.intValue() % 2 == 0)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="653" y="0" width="67" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ASSG_BUDGETAMOUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="543" y="0" width="47" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ASSG_SEQUENCE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="481" y="0" width="62" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ASSG_LIMITTO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="353" y="0" width="66" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ASSG_ISLIMITAPPLICABLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="419" y="0" width="61" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ASSG_LIMITFROM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="0" width="214" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box leftPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ASSG_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="590" y="0" width="63" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ASSG_ISBUDGETAPPLICABLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="215" y="0" width="79" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box leftPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ASSG_CODE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="294" y="0" width="59" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box leftPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACTP_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="720" y="0" width="82" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACSG_NATURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="18" width="800" height="1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{AccountSubGroupName_COUNT}.intValue()<1)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="20">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="652" y="1" width="113" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Verdana"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="765" y="1" width="37" height="19"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Verdana"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: What API are you using: JasperReports or DynamicJasper?

Comment: @Alex K : Sorry for late reply ...i am using Jasper API

Answer (score 2):

For groups, I believe you can set the `Keep Together` property on the group and/or subgroups to handle this.

**Keep Together Description:**

> Flag that prevents the group from splitting on two seperate
>   pages/columns, but only on the first break attempt

Comment: Thanks jschoen..but if i do so ,each group will not split and go to the next page... But i dont mind the group splitting on 2 pages but the group headers should not be the last line on the page and data on the next page.

Comment: If you update your question with the JRXML I may be able to help.

Comment: Now I understand what you are saying. Unfortunately there is not a way to do that. The closest you will be able to get is using the Keep together flag. But like you said it will always split if the group will not fit on the page. It would be a nice feature to be able to say insert link break if group is in the bottom %X of page.