# Jasper Report: Page break and remaning content goes to next page

Tags: jasper-reports

We have used jasper report with different band for subreports. One band has table where we see page break with content span in next page, Please refer the image where earning cut down and went to next page

Jrxml code snippet

```
<band height="40" splitType="Immediate">
        <subreport overflowType="Stretch">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="40" uuid="0708d796-8c54-4efc-bc96-b74081244095">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{openAnswersList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["OpenQuestionData.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [avoiding unwanted page break in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760228/avoiding-unwanted-page-break-in-jasperreports)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I place a record into a new page in JasperReports if it overflows the last one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532280/how-do-i-place-a-record-into-a-new-page-in-jasperreports-if-it-overflows-the-las)

Comment: As you see its unclear what you need to achieve...

Comment: We need to avoid single row cutting from the table. It should be either on same page or the whole record should move into next page. In image, the Earnings is moved into next page where it should be either on first page or if it does not fit there then whole record should move to next page.